# directed graphs and moving against the flow of the arrow

Tags: algorithm, graph, traversal, directed-graph

Is it possible to move against the direction indicated in a directed graph, e.g.

a -> b

Does this imply that if one were at b it would be impossible to get to a?

Comment: "Does this imply that if one were at b it would be impossible to get to a?"  You haven't provided any details at all about the implementation of your directed graph data structure, nor have you provided the traversal algorithm you are using, nor any constraints that you want to place upon the solution.  Without these, you could assume that anything is possible.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the proper interpretation of the following statement from wikipedia "In mathematics, and more specifically in graph theory, a directed graph (or digraph) is a graph, or set of nodes connected by edges, where the edges have a direction associated with them."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph
And if it truly is the case that most people would reasonably assume that anything is possible in this simple example, then I'll be sure to include that in my answers for my homework and exam. Thank you and good night.

Comment: From a programming perspective, it just means that the object that represents node a has a reference to the node b object, and the node b object does not have a reference to node a.  Your question about "moving" against the direction is not really well defined from a programming perspective, because you haven't defined what "moving" means.  I think most people would assume you are referring to [graph traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_traversal).  As I pointed out in my comment to @musical_coder, in-order depth first traversal would mean that node b gets processed first...

Comment: ... so you could interpret that as "Does this imply that if one were at b it would be impossible to get to a? No."  It all depends on what you mean by "getting" to a from b.  Node b does not give you a reference to node a, but you could traverse the graph such that node b is processed first, then node a is processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't move against the direction of the arrow.

You could get back to `a` only if there's another legal path from `b` to `a`.

Comment: What prevents someone from keeping track of the previous node while traversing the graph, so that they can reference node a after visiting node b?  What exactly do you mean by "can't move against the direction of the arrow"?

Comment: Thank you. I thought this was the case, but couldn't find an explicit statement confirming my suspicion.

Comment: As they stand, both the question and this answer are nonsensical.

Comment: It means that you can't start at the pointy end of the arrow and traverse to the other end; you can only go the other way. You're free to remember which nodes you've visited, but the OP's question is if you can shift directly from b to a in the above example. Assuming a->b is the entire graph, the answer is no.

Comment: One could easily implement a traversal algorithm for this directed graph that processes node b, and then processes node a.  For example, [in-order depth first traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29).